# Changing date format using moment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I'm using a date picker which has moment.js and currently the date format I'm getting is MM/DD/YYYY. I want to change this format to DD/MM/YYYY. How do I do that?

This is how I call the date picker component.

```
<DatePickerComponent
    datePickerClass={"form-control quick-checkout-input-filed" +   (this.state.errorFields.dob ? " error-field" : "")}
    datePickerId="dob"
    datePickerName="dob"
    datePickerMaxDate={moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}
    datePickerChangeAction={this.onChangeAction}
    datePickerBlurAction={this.onBlurAction}
    datePickerPlaceholder="Select Date"
/>
```

I've also attached a screenshot of the datepicker.
[image: Datepicker]

> This is my component.

```js
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';

// sample DatePickerComponent calling way

class DatePickerComponent extends PureComponent{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.clickFieldHandler=this.clickFieldHandler.bind(this);
        this.onBlurFieldHandler=this.onBlurFieldHandler.bind(this);
        this.state={fieldType: "text"};
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div key="name_1">
                <input
                    onFocus={ this.clickFieldHandler }
                    placeholder={ this.props.datePickerPlaceholder }
                    type={ this.state.fieldType }
                    className={ this.props.datePickerClass }
                    id={ this.props.datePickerId }
                    name={ this.props.datePickerName }
                    defaultValue={ this.props.datePickerValue }
                    min={ this.props.datePickerMinDate }
                    max={ this.props.datePickerMaxDate }
                    onChange = { this.props.datePickerChangeAction }
                    onBlur={ this.onBlurFieldHandler }
                    disabled={ this.props.datePickerIsDissabled }
                />
            </div>
        );
    }

    clickFieldHandler(event){
        this.setState({ fieldType: "date" });
    }

    onBlurFieldHandler(event){
        if(event.target.value.length === 0){
            this.setState({ fieldType: "input" });
        }
        if(this.props.datePickerBlurAction){
            this.props.datePickerBlurAction(event);
        }
    }

}

export default React.memo(DatePickerComponent);
```

Comment: Which datepicker library do you use? Please, provide more information.

Comment: @MikhailGrechka I'm using moment.js date library

Comment: @Vins98 `DatePickerComponent` is not related to `moment.js` It's either your custom component or it comes from some library. What is it ?

Comment: Show your component please

Comment: @MikhailGrechka I'm sorry for not providing all the information previously. I've updated the question now and have included my component

Comment: @ikos23 it's a custom component. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I m currently using moment library to change date formate like

Moment('03/03/2021').format('YYYY-MM-DD')

Comment: I tried this too but still the format goes as MM/DD/YYYY even if the format I've given is YYYY/MM/DD

Comment: which library version did you used ? or can u try with let date = "2018-06-02T10: 00: 00"
let correctDate = moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH: mm: ss').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm') pass date with format

Comment: I used the ^2.29.1 version

Comment: yes same version I m using mine is work with this solution